# IPtables Linux Firewall and IPsec traffic

Tags: linux, firewalls, ipsec, iptables

Can iptables filter out incoming datagrams that are IPSec-tunneled packets going to port 25?

Comment: You should be able to drop them based on protocol (e.g. AH, ESP, ISAKMP).  So UDP then give the port number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean "can host X, which terminates the IPSec tunnel, apply iptables filters to the de-tunneled traffic?" then the answer is **yes**.

Here's a Server Fault Q&A on this exact topic - [With iptables, match packets arrived via IPSEC tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/463440/with-iptables-match-packets-arrived-via-ipsec-tunnel) - which states

> You need to use the policy module, and specify the ipsec policy, to
>   match this traffic.

and gives as an example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
```

Unfortunately, documentation is pretty sparse.  Googling for it will find you things like [this](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2006-February/064787.html):

> I'm looking for for in-depth documentation for the iptables "ipsec 
>   policy match" module. It might be just the right thing to solve my 
>   iptables/ipsec-problems; but the information given with "iptables -m 
>   policy -h" is not very intuitive.

(and of course some help for using it is found in the ensuing thread).